# Is a subdomain of an Euclidean domain an Euclidean domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is every subdomain of an Euclidean domain also an Euclidean domain?

I'm having some trouble grasping some of the concepts, so could someone please help with this question?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Firstly let's think of a non-Euclidean domain - $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.
Note that every Euclidean domain is a pid (principal ideal domain). For a proof I suggest [this textbook](http://abstract.ups.edu/download/aata-20160809.pdf) (Theorem 18.21). To check that $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is a non-Euclidean domain consider the
ideal $<X,2>$, and conclude it's not principal.

Now $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ will be the subdomain, so we should look for
something that contains it and that is an Euclidean domain. $\mathbb{Q}[X]$
is field (in particular it is a integral domain) so it has $\mathbb{Z}[X]$
as its subdomain. Also note that there is a division algorithm for rings
of polynomials with coefficients in a field, and its valuation is the
degree of the polynomial. Alternatively, we can think of the field
of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and take $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ as its subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. Technically speaking, all fields can be considered Euclidean domains, and *every* domain is a subring of a field.

If your definition of an Euclidean ring does not allow fields, then just add a variable: 
Whenver $D$ is any domain whatsoever, we have its field of fractions $k$. Then
$$D \subseteq k \subseteq k[X]$$
and $k[X]$ is an Euclidean domain.

Comment: I'm a tad confused with your answer. I believe my definition does allow for fields being Euclidean domains. Are you then saying that I can find a subring of a field where this subring would also not be a field? Do you mind giving a concrete example of a subdomain of an Euclidean domain that is not an Euclidean domain?

Comment: @Cici The point is that _every_ domain embeds into some field (the universal choice of such field is called the field of fractions, or the quotient field of the domain). So if you start with a domain that is not Euclidean, you have a subring of a field which is not Euclidean. To be more concrete, let us consider some example, Let's say $D=\mathbb{Z}+x\mathbb{Q}[x]=\{f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]\;|\; f(0) \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Then this is not Neotherian, hence non-Euclidean. But clearly $D$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}(x), $ the field of all rational functions with coeff. in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thank you so much for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your confusion lies in thinking that having an euclidean function is a universal property, when it is actually a $\forall \exists$-property.

So if $\varphi$ is an euclidean function on the ring $R$, and $R'$ is a subring, for $(a,b) \in  R' \times (R' - \{0\})$, there are $q,r$ **in $\mathbf{R}$** such that $a = bq + r$ with $r=0$ or $\varphi(r) < \varphi(b)$.

Since both $q$ and $r$ are only known to be in $R$, one can't conclude that they are in $R'$ by knowing that $a$ and $b$ are.